# React-router allow user access a url in the domain that is in the server and nt a part of the SPA

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a react single page application in a domain for example `domain.com`, 
I want to allow users to get to WordPress site that is in `domain.com/blog` URL
I tried to do that by creating a new component called `blog` and in the component I redirected to `domain.com/blog`. I have arrived that url but I receive an empty page (which means I am still in the SPA).
How can I exclude a URL from the SPA?

This is the blog component code:

`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Blog extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            (window.location = 'https ://domain.com/blog')
        )
    }
}

export default Blog
```

`

Comment: have you use redirect element? a simple href?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to redirect to an external link like this:

```
<Route path='/blog' component={() => { 
     window.location.href = 'https://example.com/blog'; 
     return null;
}}/>
```

This should trigger a refresh and load your page.